# How to show dialog in service on android

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-dialog

In my application I want to use `service` and in this `service` I should show layout.
I want when **click on** `button` show `dialog`, I write below codes!
But after **click on** `button`, show this `dialog` back of layout and not show any `dialog`!

**My service codes :**

```
public class FloatingLayoutService extends Service implements StepperFormListener {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        //Inflate the layout using LayoutInflater
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        floatingLayout = (ConstraintLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.service_floating_layout, null);

        floatingLay_root = floatingLayout.findViewById(R.id.floatingLay_root);
        floatingLay_main = floatingLayout.findViewById(R.id.floatingLay_main);
        floatingLay_emptyImg = floatingLayout.findViewById(R.id.floatingLay_emptyImg);
        ...

        //Set layout params to display the controls over any screen.
        int LAYOUT_FLAG;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
        }
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                0,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        // From API26, TYPE_PHONE deprecated. Use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY for O
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
        //Initial position of the floating controls
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.START;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;
        //Add the controls view to windowManager
        windowManager.addView(floatingLayout, params);

        //Task page btn
        floatingLay_infoContentNextPage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .create();

            alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            alertDialog.show();

        });

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

How can I show `dialog`, front of `layout` ?

Comment: Do you want to make an alert dialog?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin, yes for this i write below codes            `AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .create();

            alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            alertDialog.show();`

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin, can you help me?

Comment: Do you have the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`?

Comment: @npk, yes my friend! i added this into manifest file.

Comment: I attached you an example alert dialog@Dr.KeyOk

Comment: @npk, can you help me? please

Comment: A service is supposed to perform a background task and show the user a notification if the task is ongoing. If you are trying to show an alertdialog from a service, then you probably shouldn't use a service. You should resort to using something else. Always use the right APIs for the right jobs

Comment: @Rafsanjani there are use cases like an alarm where this is required

Comment: @Rafsanjani, hey dear i should record screen and when record screen i should show some layouts for some works! for this i should use service! and i want when click on one of this buttons show one dialog!

Answer (score 0):

You can make an activity without a layout just to show the Alert dialog.

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Message")
                ...
                ...
                .show()
    }
}
```

Remember to finish the activity.

You can set the title and message dynamically by passing them through intent.

**Service**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlertDialog.class);
intent.putExtra("titleKey", "title");
intent.putExtra("messageKey", "messge");
startActivity(intent);
```

And inside the activity, read it as:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("titleKey")
getIntent().getStringExtra("messageKey")
```